# What determines the weapon sold by the black market weapon trader?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I encountered a Black Market Weapon trader in my journey across the cosmos, and it was offering an unknown weapon for 65 scrap. I'm leery of putting down 65 scrap on a weapon with no idea what it is.

What determines the weapon sold by the Black Market Trader? Is it completely random, and if so, what are possible weapons it can sell me?

[image]

Comment: Just a note, it can also sell you nothing. Scamming you. "Hahaha, remember what I told you about the dangers of the nebula!"

Comment: yes, but you do get the option to attack them and blow them up for revenge *evil grin*.  Anyway, its possible that its entirely random, but it could also be limited to only weapons that cost more than 65 scrap to purchase.

Comment: @yx. the funny thing is that if you destroy their ship, board them to death, or they surrender, you still don't seem to get any of that Scrap back... so where did it all go?

Comment: @Krazer It was immediately transferred to a Caymans bank account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a 50% chance he will renege. If not, the weapon is completely random (probably with uniform distribution, as with other random choices in the game, but maybe biased by the `rarity` attribute).

You can verify this in the `NEBULA_WEAPONS_TRADER_LIST` event data.